# Wrapping Every Two Divs in Loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

My HTML Structure is as follows:

```
<div class="container">

<div class=row 1>
<img src="#" />
<img src="#" />
</div>

<div class=row 2>
<img src="#" />
<img src="#" />
</div>

<div class=row 3>
<img src="#" />
<img src="#" />
</div>

</div>
```

I will use `for each` loop. After each two iterations of `for each` loop, I want to start new container `div` and  `row 1`, `row 2` and `row 3` `div`s. I mean main `div` should wrap 3 rows and each row `div` will wrap two images or `div`. I am using a single loop. How should I apply the `for each` loop counter for this?

Comment: Please show us your foreach loop.

Comment: This sounds like a job for **`MODULO`** http://php.net/manual/de/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of images or other content you want to put into those divs. This is the concept of what you have to do, then you can adapt it as you need or use your favorite coding styling:

```
<?php

$contents = array('img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg','img4.jpg','img5.jpg','img6.jpg');

echo '<div class="container">'; 

$rowCount = 0;

foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {

    if ($key % 2 == 0) {

        if ($key > 0) {

            echo "</div><!--close .row-->";
        }

        $rowCount++;

        echo '<div class="row row' . $rowCount . '"><!--opening .row-->';
    }

    echo '<img src="' . $value . '" alt="This is image: ' . $value . '">';

}

echo '</div><!--close .row-->';
echo '</div><!--close .container-->';
```

It will render:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row1"><!--opening .row-->
        <img src="img1.jpg" alt="This is image: img1.jpg">
        <img src="img2.jpg" alt="This is image: img2.jpg">
    </div><!--close .row-->
    <div class="row row2"><!--opening .row-->
        <img src="img3.jpg" alt="This is image: img3.jpg">
        <img src="img4.jpg" alt="This is image: img4.jpg">
    </div><!--close .row-->
    <div class="row row3"><!--opening .row-->
        <img src="img5.jpg" alt="This is image: img5.jpg">
        <img src="img6.jpg" alt="This is image: img6.jpg">
    </div><!--close .row-->
</div><!--close .container-->
```

It will work with whatever amount of images you put in your array.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Actually what I want is new container after every two rows.

Comment: The code I provided can easily be adapted to add/nest more divs. Sorry if it didn't work can you please provide me an example of what out put you wish to accomplish? In example by adding an other if ($key % 2 == 0) { /* your code here */ } you can have the loop add anything else you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array chunk to do that, see the following code :

```
foreach (array_chunk($yourArray, 2, true) as $results)
{
     <div class="row">
      foreach($results as $result)
       {
         //display it here 
       }
     </div>
}
```